# porque no permite instalar la dependencia de material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Estoy tratando de instalar la libreria de material ui con el comando que viene en su documentacion pero en la terminal me esta mandando un error que puedo hacer para corregir ese error y poder instalar la dependencia

estoy usando esta instruccion `npm install @material-ui/core` justo como viene en la documentacion e igual adjuto imagen del error que me esta mandando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer el [tour] para entender como funciona Stackoverflow y el apartado [ask] para tener las pautas necesarias para que tu pregunta capte la atención y sea respondida. También proporciona un [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho o errores que tienes y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La versión que estás intentando instalar de Material UI es una versión antigua y creo que incluso deprecada que no soporta React 18.

Prueba instalando la última versión de Material UI como indica aquí: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/material o en su documentación oficial [https://mui.com](https://mui.com/)

Otra solución si "sí o sí" quieres esta versión es instalar previamente React en su versión 16 o 17, y entonces instalar la librería en la versión que quieres. Por ejemplo: `npm i react@16.14.0`

Comment: listo si funciono gracias

Answer (score 0):

Ese error te da por que hay conflicto con las versiones de las dependencias, es común cuando trabajas con versiones antiguas que no han sido actualizadas o ya no se mantienen.

Para solucionarlo puedes usar el parametro "--legacy-peer-deps" con el cual permites que npm instale dependencias antiguas, en lugar de la mas reciente para que sea compatible con la versión que tienes de React.

Usando `npm install @material-ui/core --legacy-peer-deps` deberia solucionarse tu problema.

Es importante recalcar que las dependencias antiguas podrían tener vulnerabilidades de seguridad, por lo que es recomendable actualizarlas de ser posible a la mas reciente.